# Dumping android SQLite text content into textView

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I built an app that so far manages to ADD text to a database (cannot verify yet but I killed the FC). However, when I try to read from the database it FCs because I'm unsure of how to use the Cursor object. I read the documentation and it confuses me more. I have a database with table "records" and a single column "texts". While my project manages to input text into the database (via an EditText), I'm trying unsuccessfully to return all the database entries from this "texts" column into a textView.

DB Helper inner-class:

```
private class dbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public dbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        System.out.println("create statement"+SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
        try
        {
            db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);

        }catch(SQLiteException sql)
        {
            sql.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS records");
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public void addRecord(String t) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
        values.put(RECORDS_COLUMN_TEXTS,t);

        getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_NAME, RECORDS_COLUMN_TEXTS, values);
    }

    public Cursor getRecords() {

        return getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);

    }   

}
```

Within main class:

```
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CSCI598";
 private static final String TABLE_NAME = "records";

 public static final String RECORDS_COLUMN_TEXTS = "texts";

 private dbHelper openHelper;

 private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + RECORDS_COLUMN_TEXTS + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" + ");"; 


public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); 

    openHelper = new dbHelper(this);

    switch(v.getId()) {

    case R.id.fetch1:
        Cursor cursor = openHelper.getRecords();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            sb.append(cursor.getString(0) + "\n");
        }
        tv.setText(sb.toString());

        break;

    case R.id.append1:
        String txt=et.getText().toString(); 
        openHelper.addRecord(txt);
        break;

}
```

logcat: http://pastebin.com/mqUn6g7P

As you can see, I'm probably trying something very stupid with the action for clicking the fetch button, ie. `"openHelper.getRecords().toString()"` attempting to convert all that `Cursor` returns to `string`. How can I go about this alternately in the simplest fashion?

Comment: Could you add the output of LogCat please?

Comment: do you want to show all the values in the column to the textView?

Comment: Why logcat? Isn't my definition for printing text from database very illegal? I'm looking for a correction in the code.. Please read my last paragraph.

Comment: @Peshal yeah, I want all the values in "texts" column to show up per line in the multi-line textView.

Comment: On clicking append, noticed logcat saying no such table: records & error inserting texts:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok First you have get the strings from the Cursor by doing this

```
Cursor cursor = openHelper.getRecords();
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
    sb.append(cursor.getString(0) + "\n");
}
```

Then you can set it to the textView

```
 tv.setText(sb.toString);
```

This should work actually
.Replace this part of your code

```
case R.id.fetch1:
        tv.setText(openHelper.getRecords().toString());
        break;
```

With this

```
case R.id.fetch1:
Cursor cursor = openHelper.getRecords();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        sb.append(cursor.getString(0) + "\n");
    }
tv.setText(sb.toString);
break;
```

Also remove autoincrement for Text when you create the table
Replace this:

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + RECORDS_COLUMN_TEXTS + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" + ");";
```

With this:

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + RECORDS_COLUMN_TEXTS + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Also Add table name in the constructor instead of database name. Change this:

```
public dbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }
```

To this:

```
 public dbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }
```

Comment: I added a logcat error in comments on OP. Also, this code is still giving FCs. Unsure if the database is even created/working ?

Comment: i updated the answer did you change exactly like this

Comment: "No such table: records while compiling select * from ..." from logcat, then FC.

Comment: why are you using AUTOINCREMENT for text? i think that's the issue. you have to remove that. Its mainly used for ids that are numeric

Comment: Thanks, yeah. Removed AUTOINCREMENT, still same issue, logcat.

Comment: did you remove that ; too in the create statement see my updated answer you dont need ; within the create statement

Comment: Right. Changed that, still the same result. Updated OP with current code.

Comment: ok, can you post the entire logcat to the question so we can look more into the issue

Comment: logcat after only just clicking fetch (and FC) posted here: http://pastebin.com/mqUn6g7P

Comment: ok one more thing i can think of try changing the sql `select * from " + TABLE_NAME` to `select texts from " + TABLE_NAME` in your `getRecords()` method. But its complaining your table is not yet there. Can you also try uninstalling the app and installing again?

Comment: Didn't work.. I'm wondering if there's some issue with accessing the database? Should I mandatorily have to define the DB path or something?

Comment: see my last update you constructor seems incorrect too

Comment: WORKS !! It was the constructor! I also needed to add code to prevent duplicate entries from being added to database.. can you help with that too? Or should I start a new question?